# Saving and restoring entire fragment stacks in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Android app that uses fragments (via the ACP) within an activity. I've got multiple "modes"; in each mode, I have a sequence of fragments that I might want to show, and I'm managing the back stack normally. However, when switching modes, I want to be able to save and restore the entire stack, so that the state of each mode is persistent.

In other words, if the user is in mode 1 and opens fragments A, B, and C (in order), switches to mode 2 and opens fragments D and E, and then switches back to mode 1, I want them to see fragment C and have A and B on the back stack.

Anyone know of a way to achieve this effect?

Thanks,
    Aaron

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this with nested fragments.Android support library supports Nested Fragments now

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Nested Fragments. Android support library supports Nested Fragments now. 
This will enable you to use Fragment inside Fragment achieving your design goal.

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html#Notes